# Querying Multiple DataSet for GA4 in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

In this case, I am trying to query across multiple GA4 datasets... each represent a different website and live in a different dataset.

I am familiar with querying across different tables within a dataset using the _Table_Suffix function... but I cannot figure out how to query multiple tables.

For Example:

```
SELECT 
FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3
FROM `myproject.mydataset1.20230401`
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3
FROM `myproject.mydataset2.20230401`
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3
FROM `myproject.mydataset3.20230401`
```

I would like something like

```
SELECT 
FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3
FROM `myproject.*.20230401`
WHERE _TABLE_NAME in ("mydataset1","mydataset2","mydataset3")
```

Anyone familiar with this approach? I am trying to increase performance and not use UNION ALLS

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, BigQuery does not support wildcard characters for dataset names. So you cannot use something like `myproject.*.20230401` to reference multiple datasets.